# Any way to replace pandas pd.merge?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe

```
>>df1.info()
>><class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
  Int64Index: 2598374 entries, 3975 to 3054366
  Data columns (total 14 columns): ......
>>df2.info()
>><class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
  Int64Index: 2520405 entries, 2066 to 2519507
  Data columns (total 5 columns): ......
```

I wanna inner join them. I tried `pd.merge` and I got memory error. Thus, I tried to do same things without `pd.merge`.

Example dataframe for original method (failed: memory error)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '2', '3', '4','5'],
              'B': ['1', '1', '1', '1','1'],
              'C': ['c', 'A1', 'a', 'c3','a'],
              'D': ['B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3','B4'],
              'E': ['3', '3', '3', '3','3'],
              'F': ['3', '4', '5', '6','7'],
              'G': ['2', '2', '2', '2','2']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '2',  '8','4'],
              'B': ['1', '2',  '5','1'],
              'x': ['3', '3', '2','2'],
              'y': ['3', '4', '6','7'],
              'z': ['2', '2', '2','2']})
>>   df1
         A  B   C   D  E  F  G
      0  1  1   c  B1  3  3  2
      1  2  1  A1  B1  3  4  2
      2  3  1   a  B2  3  5  2
      3  4  1  c3  B3  3  6  2
      4  5  1   a  B4  3  7  2

     df2
         A  B  x  y  z
      0  1  1  3  3  2
      1  2  2  3  4  2
      2  8  5  2  6  2
      3  4  1  2  7  2

df1 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='inner',on=['A','B']) 

>>   df1    
         A  B   C   D  E  F  G  x  y  z
      0  1  1   c  B1  3  3  2  3  3  2
      1  4  1  c3  B3  3  6  2  2  7  2
```

Example for new method
(1) I tried to delete rows in df1 which are not in df2 by column['A']['B'].
(2) concat x,y,z columns to df1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '2', '3', '4','5'],
              'B': ['1', '1', '1', '1','1'],
              'C': ['c', 'A1', 'a', 'c3','a'],
              'D': ['B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3','B4'],
              'E': ['3', '3', '3', '3','3'],
              'F': ['3', '4', '5', '6','7'],
              'G': ['2', '2', '2', '2','2']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '2',  '8','4'],
              'B': ['1', '2',  '5','1'],
              'x': ['3', '3', '2','2'],
              'y': ['3', '4', '6','7'],
              'z': ['2', '2', '2','2']})
>>   df1
         A  B   C   D  E  F  G
      0  1  1   c  B1  3  3  2
      1  2  1  A1  B1  3  4  2
      2  3  1   a  B2  3  5  2
      3  4  1  c3  B3  3  6  2
      4  5  1   a  B4  3  7  2

     df2
         A  B  x  y  z
      0  1  1  3  3  2
      1  2  2  3  4  2
      2  8  5  2  6  2
      3  4  1  2  7  2

df1 = df1.loc[((df1['A'].isin(df2.A)) & (df1['B'].isin(df2.B)) ) ]

>>   df1    
         A  B   C   D  E  F  G  
      0  1  1   c  B1  3  3  2  
      1  2  1  A1  B1  3  4  2
      3  4  1  c3  B3  3  6  2
```

however, I got a logical error and I have no idea to solve this problem.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried `df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='inner',on=['A','B']) `?

Comment: @JoeR yes,I've tried. got the same problem

Comment: Depending on your real data you may want to categorize your some/all columns - this might save some RAM, especially if there are lots of duplicated values in columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some multi-index problems by use `isin()` then `pd.concat`.
I solved the problem by `np.array_split`.

step 1:
split the dataframe to 5 dataframe

```
dfa,dfb,dfc,dfd,dfe = np.array_split(df1,5)
```

step 2:
merge them separately

```
dfa = pd.merge(dfa,df2,how='inner',on=['A','B'])
dfb = pd.merge(dfb,df2,how='inner',on=['A','B'])
dfc = pd.merge(dfc,df2,how='inner',on=['A','B'])
dfd = pd.merge(dfd,df2,how='inner',on=['A','B'])
dfe = pd.merge(dfe,df2,how='inner',on=['A','B'])
```

step 3:
append them to one dataframe

```
result = dfa.append([dfb, dfc,dfd,dfe])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1.set_index(['A','B']),
                 df2.set_index(['A','B'])], axis=1, join='inner')
print (df1)              
      C   D  E  F  G  x  y  z
A B                          
1 1   c  B1  3  3  2  3  3  2
4 1  c3  B3  3  6  2  2  7  2
```

Or combination with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df1[((df1['A'].isin(df2.A)) & (df1['B'].isin(df2.B)) ) ]
print (df1)
   A  B   C   D  E  F  G
0  1  1   c  B1  3  3  2
1  2  1  A1  B1  3  4  2
3  4  1  c3  B3  3  6  2

df2 = df2[((df2['A'].isin(df1.A)) & (df2['B'].isin(df1.B)) ) ]
print (df2)
   A  B  x  y  z
0  1  1  3  3  2
3  4  1  2  7  2

df3 = pd.concat([df1.set_index(['A','B']),
                 df2.set_index(['A','B'])], axis=1, join='inner')
print (df3)              
      C   D  E  F  G  x  y  z
A B                          
1 1   c  B1  3  3  2  3  3  2
4 1  c3  B3  3  6  2  2  7  2
```

If `df1` after filtering is not large, use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
df1 = df1[((df1['A'].isin(df2.A)) & (df1['B'].isin(df2.B)) ) ]
print (df1)
   A  B   C   D  E  F  G
0  1  1   c  B1  3  3  2
1  2  1  A1  B1  3  4  2
3  4  1  c3  B3  3  6  2

df2 = df2[((df2['A'].isin(df1.A)) & (df2['B'].isin(df1.B)) ) ]
print (df2)
   A  B  x  y  z
0  1  1  3  3  2
3  4  1  2  7  2

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['A','B']) 
print (df3)              
   A  B   C   D  E  F  G  x  y  z
0  1  1   c  B1  3  3  2  3  3  2
1  4  1  c3  B3  3  6  2  2  7  2
```

Comment: well....I got an exception about `Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`

Comment: I think you get error with `concat`. How does work last solution with `boolean indexing` and merge?

Comment: still too large to be merge :'(

Comment: I was afraid about it :(

Comment: What is size of your RAM?

Comment: Main problem is `merge` is very well implemented, so find some another solution is really hard. If use filtering by boolean indexing I think length of `df1` and `df2` is not changed. :(

Comment: I solved the problem by `np.array_split`!! I'll update the answer later. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So I can remove my answer? Or do you accept it or upvote ?